# Simple code program to print ASCII of a string (per characters) not working with input cases

Tags: c, loops

So i have created a simple program to print ASCII codes of a string per characters, in this case i must use input case(T) to toggle on how much string that i want to print to ASCII.
There are 2 problems:
The first problem is it wont read all of my input case and only read the last case of string (it was supposed to print every ASCII code of every string). The second problem is i must use "-" symbol between every ASCII but it ended up in the end of every ASCII code that is printed.
What is wrong and what should i do in this case? I am still not very fond of C Programming so i couldn't seem to find any solution for this. Here is the the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int T;
char t[1000];
scanf("%d", &T);
for(int i = 0; i < T; i++)
{
    scanf("%s", t);
    fflush(stdin);
}

for(int i = 0; i < T; i++)
{
    printf("Case %d:\n", i+1);
    for(int j = 0; t[j] != '\0'; j++)
    {
        printf("%d-", t[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

And here is the result of the program when run:

```
2
ABCDEF
GHIJKL
Case 1:
71-72-73-74-75-76-
Case 2:
71-72-73-74-75-76-

--------------------------------
Process exited after 9.87 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Mark the console with your mouse cursor and press enter, then paste the result in a text editor, so we can view it as text, rather than as an extremely high res picture.

Comment: You read all the test case strings into `char t[1000];` before you process anything - so you then process the final one repeatedly. Make the two loops into a single loop.

Comment: And don't do this: `fflush(stdin);` . Burn whatever text told you that was valid; it's UB per the C standard. `fflush` is only supported on streams open for *output*.

Comment: @Lundin ok sorry for that

Comment: @WeatherVane so should i erased the second for(int i) and implement it into the first?

Comment: The dashes: the easiest way is probably to print "-%d" unless j = 0, and then only print "%d". Or just printf("%d") and putc the dash separately. Or you could do it the other way and make an exception for the last item in the loop rather than the first, but the first is likely easier since you don't have the length of the input string to hand.

Comment: @WhozCraig i was told to use that by my former programming supervisor so that the input doesn't overlap. I didn't do any research about it. Thank you for telling me.

Comment: @WhozCraig Unless you use `#ifdef __GNUC__` ;)

Comment: ...or you could output for `t[0]` *before* the loop, without a dash, and then loop from `t[1]` with a leading dash for each.

Comment: @Rup thank you for the correct implementaton for that i will try adding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second inner for loop must be inside the first for loop.

Also the call of the function `fflush`

```
fflush(stdin);
```

has undefined behavior.

The body of the function main can look like

```
size_t n;
char s[1000];

scanf( "%zu", &n );

for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    scanf( "%s", s );

    printf( "Case %zu:\n", i+1 );

    for ( size_t j = 0; s[j] != '\0'; j++ )
    {
        if ( j != 0 ) putchar( '-' );
        printf( "%d", s[j] );
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much for the answer, but it only solved the first problem by defining in a single loop and this answer still contain the second problem which is the dash (-) symbol that was supposed to be in between every ASCII code only.

Comment: @NeoVirz See the updated inner for loop in my naswer.

Comment: Thank You for the last edit of the inner loop, both of the problems are solved.